# How to run WordPress from other location on the same domain

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi I have a domain running in WordPress,

the path to WordPress installation is `/subdomain/mywordpress/` and I can access these in `mywordpress.mysite.com`, Now I wish to load the index page on my main domain, ie

When I goto `mysite.com` I want to load the Index page of the WordPress, I know if that possible, the links are always pointing to `mywordpress.mysite.com`, but that is what I need know. because I dont want to remove the `mywordpress.mysite.com`. I just need to display all posts on my main site, with same design(that is why I prefer to load the Index file of wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

What about a simple mod_rewrite rule inside a .htaccess to redirect to mywordpress.mysite.com?

This should work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule . /subdomain/mywordpress/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this article in the Codex: [Giving WordPress Its Own Directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory). It addresses exactly the situation you are describing.